Calculation order of CSS manipulation
I want .container to have no height set, with the only source of height from .source__height. It will change at runtime and everything should work fine.
I want to keep using aspect-ration but don't mind solutions not involving flexbox


.container {
  display: flex;
  /* height: 500px; */
  /* should not need this to get it working */
}

.dependent__height {
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.source__height {
  width: 10px;
  height: 500px;
  /* can change arbitrary */
  background-color: tomato;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="dependent__height"></div>
  <div class="source__height"></div>
</div>



I tried a lot of hops around, also JavaScript. JavaScript might work if use MutationObserver and sync heights, but is very clumsy and for my use case would be really painful to write and maintain.
It works fine if .container has set height:

But not if height property removed:

Note: in real world scenario I use <img> and the problem is the approximately the same and can be solved with a solution to that problem. If you want to have more real world example, I can add it too.

It is not at all clear what you're asking here. What is the problem? What goes wrong?

@Pointy if .container doesn't have an explicit height set, then .dependent__height will not size as expected (I am getting a calculated height of 500px, but width of 0, when I test the given example in Chrome.)

@Pointy I've added details to the problem, is it enough to reopen the question?

@CBroe but .container does have a height; that's what I mean by the problem being unclear.

@Pointy yes, but they want to be able to get rid of that height, and still have it behave the same: "What I want to achieve is that .container will not have height set and the only source of height would be .source__height."

I don't think flexbox layouting takes into account aspect-ratio

Here is a way to get towards what you want with grid:


.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100% max-content;
}

.dependent__height {
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.source__height {
  width: 10px;
  height: 500px;
  /* can change arbitrary */
  background-color: tomato;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="dependent__height"></div>
  <div class="source__height"></div>
</div>



If there isn't enough width however, your dependent height at 16/9 will not have the width to grow to desired full height at that aspect ratio. One solution is to set a height of 100% however that will cause it to overflow the container (Outline added to illustrate this):


.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100% max-content;
  outline: 4px solid skyblue;
}

.dependent__height {
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.source__height {
  width: 10px;
  height: 500px;
  /* can change arbitrary */
  background-color: tomato;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="dependent__height"></div>
  <div class="source__height"></div>
</div>



Hopefully that's enough for you to play with and get what you want, if this doesn't exactly answer everything add detail to your question by editing it and I can update my answer
